# npm audit issue with the latest axios?

Tags: npm, axios

I mean I have no idea what to do...like I have the latest version of axios installed in package.json, npm audit fix doesnt help and I also tried to install the older versions of axios but still throwing the same error

```
Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                                
          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  High            Server-Side Request Forgery                         


  Package         axios                                               


  Patched in      >=0.21.1                                            


  Dependency of   apify                                               


  Package         axios                                               


  Patched in      >=0.21.1                                            


  Dependency of   apify                                               


  Path            apify > apify-client > axios
```

Comment: Do you have version 0.21.1? You are only showing the `npm audit` message

Comment: I updated to the latest version as well "0.21.1" still audit throwing the same error as above :/